# Using instantiated dependency in NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have the root `AppModule` in which I describe dependencies and I have `@Injectable` `JwtLocalStorage`. I wonder how can I pass `JwtLocalStorage.prototype.getToken()` as `tokenGetter` in `provideAuth()`. Is it possible? What I should to do for that?

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        // ...
        provideAuth({
            tokenGetter: () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(TASK_DI_CONFIG.jwtName)),
        }),
        { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: TASK_DI_CONFIG },
        { provide: JwtStorage, useClass: JwtLocalStorage }
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**jwt-local-storage.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtLocalStorage implements JwtStorage {
    constructor(
        @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig
    ) {

    }

    getToken() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.config.jwtName));
    }
    // ...
}
```

P.S. I'm using Angular `2.0.0-rc.5`

Comment: I don't really understand "how can I pass JwtLocalStorage.prototype.getToken() as tokenGetter in provideAuth()". What exactly to you want to pass where?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to pass `getToken()` method of `JwtLocalStorage` class to `provideAuth()` helper function as `tokenGetter` property. For now I have duplicated implementation of `getToken()` in `AppModule`.

Comment: I guess I understand now, but no idea. I guess you could use a custom `provideAuth()` method or copy the content of the method directly to your modules providers but that looks like a deterioration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using [service factory](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/FactoryProvider-interface.html#!#useFactory-anchor).
Solution looks like this

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        // ...
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: (http: Http, jwtStorage: JwtStorage) => {
                return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                    tokenGetter() {
                        return jwtStorage.getToken();
                    }
                }), http);
            },
            deps: [Http, JwtStorage]
        }
    ]
})
export class MyAwesomeModule {

}
```